# How would you setup Nuxt.js with Google Cloud Functions?

Tags: vue.js, google-cloud-functions, nuxt.js

I've been searching for this on google and so far whatever I've tried didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase recently created a tutorial for this. 
They use Google cloud functions to handle ssr and firebase hosting to host the static assets. Checkout: https://youtu.be/ZYUWsjUxxUQ

Comment: Yeah, I saw that video, but doesn't work with latest Nuxt.js

Comment: which version of Nuxt are you using?

Comment: version 1.3.0 uses Nodejs latest LTS, and cloud function still on 6.11

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use nuxt under legacy mode, which is recently supported in 
`nuxt-edge`.

https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/2714#issuecomment-393868687

I have setup a working repo on firebase here:

https://github.com/williamchong007/nuxt-ssr-firebase

Comment: Im also working on a Project that i wanna migrate from standart vue to nuxt for the SSR benefits. We use Firebase Hosting, can i contact you somewhere on discord or skype so we can type there i have some questions, or we talk here but its a bit complicated. Cheers N^

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google Cloud Run if you want to use the latest Nodejs and Nuxt.js. Use it in a similar way to Cloud Functions. 
https://cloud.google.com/run/